# How to auto refresh Power BI dataset after failure

Tags: error-handling, powerbi, dataset, refresh

I have scheduled query for a dataset in Power BI.

In case of a refresh failure, I want Power BI to "retry" to refresh the data again, up to 5 times.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

For the time being it doesn't seem possible as confirmed by this [post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/when-does-a-scheduled-refresh-retry/td-p/388092). You can play with the "Command time out in minutes(optional)" in your query when creating your data source as noted in the comments.
 [Under Advanced options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhnS6.png)


If the timeout is left blank the default is 10 minutes. So if the issue is that your queries are timing out this may be the solve for you.

Another workaround is that you can schedule your data source to update multiple times at half hour increments. [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtTz3.png). Note that depending on how big your data set is this may place a burden on the server you are pulling from. If that is the case then looking into incremental refresh would be your next go to.

Hope this helps.